# Не отправляется почта с сайта на почтовый сервер webmail

Tags: email, веб-сервер, smtp-server

На сервере настроены MX записи для отправки почты на ящик созданный в webmail,
имя ящика имеет вид example@finestra.biz

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если с простых почтовиков слать на этот ящик письма то проблем нет, а вот если с сервера на котором лежит сайт, то нечего не происходит, например даже просто через mail(example@finestra.biz,"test","test") проблема в неправильной настройке MX записей?

Или что то еще может быть? 
До этого говорят почта вроде работала и еще знаю что ящик сей настроен с каким то почтовым клиентом,но это не как же влиять не может на работу ящика ? Скорее всего что на сервере у нас не правильно настроено?

Comment: Вы можете предоставить скрипт,которым отправляете письма с  сайта? МХ-записи - это просто указываете почтовый сервер,через который будет работать ящик, и если более никаких проблем не определено в работе почтового ящика, то нужно смотреть скрипт,которым отправляются письма с сайта.

Comment: даже просто функцией mail в тестовом файле не отправляет на ящик..

Comment: Проверьте лог Вашего почтового сервера, там точно будет указано было ли письмо отправлено с сервера или нет.

Comment: На другой почтовый сервер можете послать письмо скриптом? Возможно у вас имеется какое-то ограничение (в файрволе как вариант). Приведите текст скрипта и возвращаемый им ответ. Так же, убедитесь, что с сервера, на котором выполняется скрипт, удаётся получить правильные MX записи почтового сервера.